# Laravel route query string to angular

Tags: php, laravel

I have an angular app that uses laravel on the back end. I use a regular expression to send a number of URLs to the angular app. Once there, the app itself uses the URL to display the proper module.

I am now trying to allow my site to receive input from another site and that input will come in the form of a URL with a query string such as ...

```
www.myurl.com/?thisId=23432&thisSection=4232
```

I cannot get this URL to register properly as one that is sent to the angular app. Is there a proper way in Laravel to say that a URL with a query string should go to address x?

Here are some things that I have tried so far ...

```
Route::get('/?thisId', 'MyController@mainApp');
Route::get('/\?thisId', 'MyController@mainApp');

Route::get('/{any?}', 'MyController@mainApp')->where('any', '^(?thisId[0-9a-zA-Z\=]');
Route::get('/{any?}', 'MyController@mainApp')->where('any', '^(\?thisId[0-9a-zA-Z\=]');
```

Not sure what to try now. Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Comment: *I cannot get this URL to register properly as one that is sent to the angular app* -- how did you 'send' it to angular..?

Comment: There are several routes that are sent to the URL of the single page angular app. This is in case the user enters the site at one of those URLs. Once within the app, everything is handled differently.

Comment: is the laravel part outside of your control? also, just a side note `www.myurl.com/?thisId=23432&thisSection=4232` can be **url rewrite** into `www.myurl.com/this/23432/thisSection=4232`, since actually most php implementation still accepts query string-based request and the slashes are from url rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel `Route` parameter scheme is not like this:

```
www.myurl.com/?thisId=23432&thisSection=4232
```

It works like:

```
www.myurl.com/thisId/23432/thisSection/4232
```

And for this the route is like:

```
Route::get('thisId/{thisId}/thisSection/{thisSection}', function ($thisId, $thisSection) {
    //
});
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-parameters)

Comment: Appreciate the help, but the URL is coming from an outside source. I have no control over it's structure and it has a query string in the form described above.

Comment: @JoshuaFoxworth what do you mean by *coming from an outside source* perhaps you can elaborate more on your setup/case.

Comment: A separate website pulls up a page from my site in an iframe. To determine the proper page to display, they send a query string URL to my site. I can't change this

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this ..

**URL**

```
www.myurl.com/thisId/123
```

**ROUTES**

```
Route::get('/thisId/{id?}', 'MyController@mainApp')->where('id', '[0-9a-zA-Z\=]');
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function mainApp($thisId='defaultifnoinput')
{
    // do some thing with $thisId;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the help, but the URL is coming from an outside source. While my site is setup the way you describe, the incoming URL has a query string.